# When using tkinter in python, how to call a checkbox which is in a fuction in another function?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

For example, I have the following code in a.py file:

```
import tkinter
def main():
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.title("Main")

    Var = tkinter.IntVar()
    CheckBox = tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text="test", variable=Var)
    CheckBox.grid(column=1, row=1)

    startButton = tkinter.Button(top, text="Start", command=lambda: a(Var))
    startButton.grid(column=1, row=2)

    top.mainloop()

def a(Var):
    print(Var.get())
```

and in another b.py file I have the following code

```
import a
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Test")

def run():
    a.main()

startButton = tkinter.Button(top, text="Start", command=run)
startButton.grid(column=0, row=0)

top.mainloop()
```

What I expect is when I check the checkbox, it will print 1 and if uncheck it will print 0.
However, whether I check or uncheck the checkbox, it will always print 0. How can I make the checkbox work?

Answer (score 0):

`Var` is local to `a.py` so you must find make it accessible to `b.py`. The simple `import a` is not sufficient unless if you define Var in a.py this way:

**a.py**

```
import tkinter

# Must be done here otherwise we can not declare Var above
top = tkinter.Tk() 
# Make Var available to b.py
Var = tkinter.IntVar()

def main():
    global Var
    global top

    #top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.title("Fix Ratio")

    Var = tkinter.IntVar()
    CheckBox = tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text="test", variable=Var)
    CheckBox.grid(column=1, row=1)

    startButton = tkinter.Button(top, text="Start", command=lambda: a(Var))
    startButton.grid(column=1, row=2)

    #top.mainloop()

def a(Var):
    print(Var.get())
```

**b.py**

If you want to have 2 separate windows as shown in your actual running program, you will need to rename `top` to something else in `b.py`:

```
import tkinter
import a # Var now is accessible from b.py

to = tkinter.Tk()
to.title("Conditioning")

def run():
    a.main()

startButton = program.tkinter.Button(to, text="Start", command=run)
startButton.grid(column=0, row=0)

to.mainloop()
```

**Demo:**

Here is a screenshot of running b.py above program when the checkbutton is unchecked and, later, checked:

[image]

Comment: It works but it has the second tkinter window appear before pressing the start button on the first window. Is it possible to make it work as after press the start button on the first window then the second window appears instead of making it appear first then update it? Because when controlling more windows, make them appear first is not that good. Thank you

Comment: And by the way, in my own program, I also use tkinter.Entry in the same function as checkbox, but it works fine. I have no idea why it can work fine but checkbox can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you have two instances of `Tk`. Tkinter is designed to have exactly onc instance at a time. Each instance has its own internal namespace, so variables in one instance are invisible to the other instance.